# Dealing with Realm transactions

Tags: ios, swift, transactions, realm

I have an **RESTful** **API** from which I retrieve a large set of data. I am persisting it locally using **Realm** and the following call:

```
func addObjectType(object: ObjectType){
    // Check for existence of data
    if (realm.object(ofType: ObjectType.self, forPrimaryKey: object.id) == nil) {
        // Persist your data easily
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(object)
        }
    }
}
```

The app has a feature to delete the data locally. I have implemented it as **following**:

```
func deleteAllData() {
    if(!realm.isEmpty){
        do{
            if(!realm.isInWriteTransaction) {
                realm.beginWrite()
                realm.deleteAll()
                try! realm.commitWrite()
            }
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("updateUI"), object: nil)
    }
}
```

However, looking at the **Realm** documentation I see the following:

> Indicates whether the Realm is currently in a write transaction.
>
> **Warning**
>
> Do not simply check this property and then start a write transaction
>   whenever an object needs to be created, updated, or removed. Doing so
>   might cause a large number of write transactions to be created,
>   degrading performance. Instead, always prefer performing multiple
>   updates during a single transaction.

Is my implementation correct?

I feel that I am missing some **checks**..

Comment: You should always `commitWrite ` after you finish add/update write, there's no need to check `isInWriteTransaction ` and realm said dont need to check since it will reduce performance

Comment: Should I do so also when I add a new object via write? (see first method addObjectType)

Comment: You don't need to call it if you use write closure, but check for `isInWriteTransaction ` is like ultra caution in most cases since they have write closure

Answer (score 1):

Realm's general rule-of-thumb is that you should try to minimize as many write transactions as you can. This includes batching together multiple writes inside one block, and trying to avoid transactions all together if the date hasn't actually changed.

Realm write transactions are self-contained on separate threads. If a background thread is performing a write transaction, all other transactions on other threads will be blocked. As a result of that, it's not necessary to check `isInWriteTransaction` unless a write transaction is open on that particular thread.

So, no, you're not missing any extra checks. As long as you haven't accidentally left a write transaction open somewhere else, you can even reduce the number of checks you've got there. :)